# Combine CSS syntax

Tags: html, css

I have some similar css lines and I will combine them in a shorter way. My solution didn't worked.

**css code**

```
    .class-1 span.blue  {display:none;}
    .class-2 span.blue { display:none;}
    .class-456 span.blue { display:none;}
```

**my solution**

```
    .class-1,.class-2,.class-456 span.blue  {display:none;}
```

I know arrays form PHP, but is it possible to create a group with `.class-$`, where I can put all numbers for `$`?

Maybe this question is very simple for many people here, but I can't find a solution on google, because I didn't kow how to describe it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can only combine it like this with regular CSS:

```
.class-1 span.blue,
.class-2 span.blue,
.class-456 span.blue {
    display: none;
}
```

For anything more ambitioned, I would encourage you to look for a CSS pre-compiler like [SCSS/Sass](https://sass-lang.com/). This opens up many more possible solutions. Your example could then be written like this:

```
.class-1,
.class-2,
.class-456 { 
    span.blue {
        display: none;
    }
}
```